# Updated baseUri for images to ===> undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs

I am trying to run: node utils/updateBaseUri.js to update my const baseUri to ipfs://my CID, but it keeps giving me an 'undefined' error:

Updated baseUri for images to ===> undefined

Could this be a gateway issue? This content contains 16,000 .png files. Thank you.

Here is the code:

```js
const description =
   "Resolute Climate Impact NFTs";
const baseUri = "ipfs://Qmcj57KPpeRzJBv67izjXiRUKG9T9m2V3tR7kpRhxVHA7a";   

const layersOrder = [
    { name: 'cuarto', number: 15},
    { name: 'panel', number: 12 },
    { name: 'logo', number: 19 },
    { name: 'secondary', number: 9 },
    { name: 'tertiary', number: 10 },
    { name: 'text', number: 19 },
    
];
  
const format = {
    width: 512,
    height: 512
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
node utils/update_info.js
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran this: node utils/update_info.js
and it worked :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Const can't be modified.Make it as

```
let baseUri = "ipfs://Qmcj57KPpeRzJBv67izjXiRUKG9T9m2V3tR7kpRhxVHA7a"; 
or
var baseUri = "ipfs://Qmcj57KPpeRzJBv67izjXiRUKG9T9m2V3tR7kpRhxVHA7a";
```